# Automate File upload from local folder, wait for scan to process, enter the name of the report and download report

Tags: windows, file-upload, automation

Understand that there may be no simple solution, but happy for any pointers.

I have a often repeated task of doing a vulnerability scan of my code. The steps are

1. Upload a zip of my code to the Scanning Website
2. Set some form parameters settings for the scan
3. Start and wait for the scan to complete
4. Once complete, download the scan report.

Is there way to automate the whole process. I'm on a windows machine, can a batch file do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Alec

Answer (score 0):

Powershell 'iwr' method is your friend, if you use it on cmdline not in PS console (`PowerShell.exe "Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -InFile $uploadPath -UseDefaultCredentials"`), you could simply embedd it into a batch file. Redirect output and check errorlevel to control script runtime.